# Merging/Concat rows in Pandas, based on some specific conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-formatting, merging-data

I have checked all similar questions, but haven't found a solution to what i look for (or at least i don't get it).

The following is a part of a big DataFrame.

`date     venue   result  gf  ga  team     opponent`
`2017-08-11  Home     W    4   1  Arsenal   Burnley`
`2017-08-11  Away     L    1   4  Burnley   Arsenal`
`2017-08-11  Home     D    2   0  Fulham    Leeds`
`2019-08-11  Home     D    1   0  Arsenal   Burnley`

I would like to make it on one row, if `opponent == team` on the same date.

So the goal is to get the following:

`date     venue   result  gf  ga  team     opponent   gf_opponent  ga_opponent`
`2017-08-11  Home     W    4   1  Arsenal   Burnley         1             4`
`2017-08-11  Home     D    2   0  Fulham    Leeds`
`2019-08-11  Home     D    1   0  Arsenal   Burnley`

I want to do that for the whole DataFrame, where `opponent == team` on the same date.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: i am not sure i follow the example ?  the only difference is that the second table removes the venue==away compared to the first ?

Comment: The first table consists of the same match from both perspectives.
The second one removes the second perspective and adds only the opponent values i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch the `team` and `opponent` columns during the merge:

```py
is_home = df["venue"] == "Home"
home = df[is_home]
away = df[~is_home]

home.merge(
    away[["date", "opponent", "team", "gf", "ga"]],
    left_on=["date", "team", "opponent"],
    right_on=["date", "opponent", "team"],
    how="outer",
    suffixes=("", "_opponent"),
).drop(columns=["opponent_opponent", "team_opponent"])
```

Comment: That worked exactly as i wanted. I have struggled with it quite a lot. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Do a self join  ?

```
##
df_string = '''date     venue   result  gf  ga  team     opponent
2017-08-11  Home     W      4   1  Arsenal   Burnley
2017-08-11  Away     L      1   4  Burnley   Arsenal
2017-08-11  Home     D      2   0  Fulham    Leeds
2019-08-11  Home     D      1   0  Arsenal   Burnley'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df_string),sep='\s+')

df_m = df.merge(df,left_on=['date','team'],right_on=['date','opponent'],suffixes=['_team','_opp'])
```